# Grant permissions over linked server

Tags: sql-server-2014, permissions, security, linked-server, active-directory

I need to grant select permissions to a sensitive table over the linked server. This table should only grant access to members of an AD group. I currently have other linked servers set up with remote login credentials which obviously will circumvent any permissions and grant all those who have access to the server permissions to the Linked Server. How do I go about correctly granting AD based  security pemissions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you connecting to the linked server by using impersonation or by using SQL Logins? Do you want the users to still be able to query the linked server, but not the sensitive table?

Comment: Hi @RandiVertongen, I've been using SQL Logins, for this particular instance I would like noone to have access to the linked server beyond those granted access to the table, however it would be useful to know if it's possible to grant access to the linked server and not the table as well

Comment: Hi @Krishn .... Why not add the AD security group to the SQL Server instance global security on the remote and linked server instances as well as the AD user accounts that are members of this group (I believe it'll need to be universal scope too by the way), and then just grant that group to have the select access to the table. Then when you defined the security on the instanced with the defined linked server, you will use the "**Be mad using the lgoin's current security context**", and that should ensure exactly what you are asking. Seems simply trivial to get up and running.